# Diamond inheritance with OCaml modules

Tags: ocaml

I have four modules.

Ring, Field who is a submodule of Ring, Coefficient which is a submodule of Ring, Coefficientdivisible which is a submodule of Ring and Coefficicent.

```
module type Ring = 
sig
  type t
  val add : t -> t -> t
  multiply : t -> t -> t
  val zero : t
  val one : t   
  val opposite : t                      (* a+ opposite a =0*)
end

module type Field =
sig
  include Ring
  val division : t -> t-> t
end

module type Coefficient = 
sig
  include Ring
  val stringDeCoef : t -> string
end

module type Coefficientvisible = 
sig
  include Field
  include Coefficient
end
```

When I try to compile the first three modules, it causes no problem but the fourth one returns an error message, ocamlc says:

> File "CoefficientDivisible.ml", line 7, characters 1-20:
>       Error: Multiple definition of the type name t.
>          Names must be unique in a given structure or signature.

Do you have a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Destructive substitution is often the answer to multilple definitions woes:

```
module type CoefficientDivisible = sig
   include Field
   include Coefficient with type t := t
end
```

Another option is to have smaller extension module types and combine them
explicitly to generate extended version of the base module type. For instance, 
with the following extension module types:

```
module type RingToField = sig
   type t
   val division: t -> t -> t
end
```

and

```
module type RingToCoefficient = 
sig
    type t
    val stringOfCoef : t -> string
end
```

the module types `Ring`, `Field`, and `CoefficientDivisible` have straigthforward definitions:

```
module type Field = sig
  include Ring
  include RingToField with type t := t
end 

module type Coefficient = sig
  include Ring
  include RingToCoefficient with type t := t
end

module type CoefficientDivisible = sig
  include Field
  include RingToCoefficient with type t := t
end
```